# How to get the checkout directory of project dependencies in TeamCity?

Tags: configuration, dependencies, teamcity

I am using TeamCity as build server and have a little trouble when configuring projects and their dependencies.

Eventually I want to get the checkout directory of project dependencies to configure certain build steps. For that I have the variable `%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%` for the checkout directory of the project itself.

However, I did not find something like `%dep.<dependencyID>.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%`.

Is there a way to get the checkout directory of a dependency?

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that the goal here is to use files that are generated by "build config 1" in "build config 2"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add a parameter (say `checkoutDir` ) in the first build whose value is equal to %teamcity.build.checkoutDir% . You can then fetch this value in the dependent build (either through snapshot or artefact dependency)

Answer (score 1):

I am using this myself and I can access my dependent Build's Checkout directory with...

```
%dep.<dependecyID>.teamcity.build.default.checkoutDir%
```

I believe this will only work with a Snapshot Dependency though

Comment: This seems to work for dependencies that are checked out to a folder with automatic naming. If a specify the folder manually I only got a string like `554523b6395b2878` which also did not point to the right folder

Comment: I think you will find that your custom folder will sit inside that folder of 554523b6395b2878. Eg D:\BuildAgent\Work\554523b6395b2878\MyCheckoutFolder. If this is the case, you might be able to Setup a parameter for the name of your Custom Checkout Directory, use this Parameter in the VCS Checkout Directory instead of hard coding, and then reference the path using %dep.<dependecyID>.teamcity.build.default.checkoutDir%\%MyCustomCheckoutPath% ????

Comment: If you want the full path you will have to get the Agent path + the checkoutDir and your custom relative path. Eg. %teamcity.agent.home.dir%\%dep.<dependecyID>.teamcity.build.default.checkoutDir%\%MyCustomCheckoutPath%

Comment: Yes, that's the way I do it now. I still lack a way of refering via a variable to a non-default path.